# How to set a custom object's method as widget callback

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have defined a class that inherits from a Tkinter widget.
Now, I would like to bind a callback that is actually a method of the custom object to its parent widget. How can I do that?

Currently, I have something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class MyLabel(ttk.Label):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Label.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.ntimes = 0

    def test(self):
        self.ntimes += 1
        self.configure(
            text='Now the label has changed {} times'.format(self.ntimes)
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    f = ttk.Frame(root)
    f.grid()
    l = MyLabel(f, text='A label')
    l.grid()
    root.bind('<Left>', l.test)
    root.mainloop()
```

but I get the error:

```
TypeError: test() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

*Note:* This is just a simplified example; I could have used the `textvariable` option of `ttk.Label` objects to have a dynamically updating text, but I wanted to focus on the general problem I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define `test` to be able to take the `event` as an argument:

```
def test(self, event):
    ...
```

If you don't want to do that, you can bind a `lambda` function to the callback:

```
root.bind('<Left>', lambda e: l.test())
```